# C# Getting a lot of 0 ms reply while ping an IP address

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of ip address and trying to get reply with `PingReply` class but it's returns a lot of 0 ms while the ip address is live and reachable, why?

```
Ping srvPing = new Ping();
PingReply reply = srvPing.Send("195.228.152.149", 1000); // example ip which returns 0 ms

String ping = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString();
Debug.WriteLine(ping + "ms");
//output: 0ms
```

Comment: _If the Echo request fails, the RoundtripTime time is reported as 0, which is also a valid value when the request succeeds. You must check the Status to determine whether the value returned by this property should be ignored._

Comment: Yes, I know but the IP is still live, then why the value of the status is not success? I don't understand. It's a game server's ip address I can connect to the game server but can't ping the ip?

Comment: Are you able to ping the computer through command line (CMD)?

Comment: No. But can connect to the game server that's why I don't understand what is happening? and this is happens with a lot of ip address which in the list. they're need some special params or what?

Comment: This isn't a programming question then. Individual computer and networks can block the ping port/protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `Status` property from your `reply` variable. If the value of `Status` is not `Success`, you should not use the values returned by the `RoundtripTime`. The `RoundtripTime` property will return zero in that case.